# A problem with a strange flickering/undulating effect and a related question about drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, graphics, flicker

I have been having a very frustrating problem in Ubuntu. Sometimes, there is a graphical effect that can only be described as flickering or undulation. I think undulation is the most accurate one, since that is really what it looks like, like the bottom of a pool of clear water. It used to happen on windows as well, when I was doing graphically intensive things, but it started appearing on Ubuntu even when I was just browsing the internet.

I thought it might be a problem with drivers, so I tried to find proper drivers on Ubuntu. Well, this is where I got completely stuck. The proprietary drivers that apparently work the best turned out to not work for my graphics card (since it is an older card). My card is an ATI Radeon HD 4670.

I have several questions.
1) I did everything I could to find working drivers for my card on my OS (Ubuntu 13.04) but I did not find anything. What is the best driver I could get, and where could I get it? People have suggested several open source drivers already but I'm not sure which to install, and which are the best.
2) I downgraded my Xserver in an attempt to install a proprietary driver, and I could not do it. As embarrassing as it is, now I do not know how to upgrade my Xserver again. When looking for Xserver upgrades, I ultimately found four packages. I did not know which one was which, so I just left it downgraded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AMD has declared the Radeon HD 2000, 3000 and 4000 series as having "legacy" support. The legacy drivers can be downloaded here:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

**However, the support from AMD is basically nonexistent.**

The legacy drivers have their share of problems, but they work well for the most part.

The best way to install the legacy drivers is using this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx

You don't need to downgrade your X server or anything like that, the PPA handles everything.

### Steps:

Open a terminal (i.e. ctrl+alt+t) and type the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Then just follow the instructions (input your password, press enter, etc.)

After this, restart your computer and the new drivers should be working.

Comment: And for future reference, the best way to install _anything_ in Ubuntu (that isn't in the default repositories) is to Google for a PPA.